# C# Should I initialize a bool as false or should I make it false in an else statement? Best practice?

Tags: c#, boolean

I have the two following pieces of code, in one I initialize the `isSpclChar` bool as `false`, in the other one I catch the false state later in an else statement:

```
static bool CheckSpclChar(char _letter)
{
    bool isSpclChar = false;

    if(_letter == '!' || _letter == '@')
    {
        isSpclChar = true;
    }

    return isSpclChar;
}
```

And:

```
static bool CheckSpclChar(char _letter)
{
    bool isSpclChar;

    if(_letter == '!' || _letter == '@')
    {
        isSpclChar = true;
    }
    else
    {
    isSpclChar = false;
    }

    return isSpclChar;
}
```

Which of them is best practice or less prone to errors in this type of case?
Does it not matter at all?

Comment: You need just one line in the method: `return _letter == '!' || _letter == '@';`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need for an `else` at all:

```cs
bool isSpecialChar = _letter == '!' || _letter == '@';
```

In fact, your whole method can be simplified to:

```cs
static bool CheckSpecialChar(char letter) => letter == '!' || letter == '@';
```

I've expanded "Spcl" to "Special" for better readability, and removed the leading prefix from the parameter name to follow [.NET conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions). You might also want to consider using `Is` instead of `Check`.

Finally, you might want to avoid using the word "special" in the method name too. I tend to wince when I hear the phrase "special character" because without more specific context, it's meaningless. What do `!` and `@` mean in this context? Is there a more useful description you could give, such as `IsEscapePrefix` or something similar?

Comment: Oh my goodnes! Whole load of useful advice there... Thank you, as you can probably tell, I'm just getting started, advice like this is unvaluable for me.

Answer (score 0):

We should use variables when we need to use that values, otherwise you just need to write your method as follows. Let me know, if that makes sense?

```
static bool CheckSpclChar(char _letter)
 {
     if(_letter == '!' || _letter == '@')
     {
       return true;
     }

     return false;
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, no need to create a boolean variable on this method at all, thank you!

Comment: You are well come!